# I need to put script from jsFiddle to work

Tags: javascript, image, radio-button

I have one small problem... I need to put this script http://jsfiddle.net/mctcs/ to work on my page, but I don't know how to do it. What to copy where, and how to make jquery working! I don't have pre-knowledge about jquery and don't know how it functions.

```
(function($){

$.fn.imageTick = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        tick_image_path: "images/radio.gif",
        no_tick_image_path: "no_images/radio.gif",
        image_tick_class: "ticks_" + Math.floor(Math.random()),
        hide_radios_checkboxes: false
    };

    var opt = $.extend(defaults, options);

    this.each(function(){

        var obj = $(this);
        var type = obj.attr('type'); // radio or checkbox

        var tick_image_path = typeof opt.tick_image_path == "object" ?
            opt.tick_image_path[this.value] || opt.tick_image_path["default"] :
            opt.tick_image_path;

        var no_tick_image_path = function(element_id) {
            var element = document.getElementById(element_id) || { value: "default" };
            return typeof opt.no_tick_image_path == "object" ?
                opt.no_tick_image_path[element.value] || opt.no_tick_image_path["default"]:
                opt.no_tick_image_path;
        }

        // hide them and store an image background
        var id = obj.attr('id');
        var imgHTML = '<img src="' + no_tick_image_path(id) + '" alt="no_tick" class="' + opt.image_tick_class + '" id="tick_img_' + id + '" />';

        obj.before(imgHTML);
        if(!opt.hide_radios_checkboxes){
            obj.css('display','none');
        }

        // if something has a checked state when the page was loaded
        if(obj.attr('checked')){
            $("#tick_img_" + id).attr('src', tick_image_path);
        }

        // if we're deadling with radio buttons
        if(type == 'radio'){

            // if we click on the image
            $("#tick_img_"+id).click(function(){
                $("." + opt.image_tick_class).each(function() {
                    var r = this.id.split("_");
                    var radio_id = r.splice(2,r.length-2).join("_");
                    $(this).attr('src', no_tick_image_path(radio_id))
                });
                $("#" + id).trigger("click");
                $(this).attr('src', tick_image_path);
            });

            // if we click on the label
            $("label[for='" + id + "']").click(function(){
                $("." + opt.image_tick_class).each(function() {
                    var r = this.id.split("_");
                    var radio_id = r.splice(2,r.length-2).join("_");
                    $(this).attr('src', no_tick_image_path(radio_id))
                });
                $("#" + id).trigger("click");
                $("#tick_img_" + id).attr('src', tick_image_path);
            });

        }

        // if we're deadling with checkboxes
        else if(type == 'checkbox'){

            $("#tick_img_" + id).click(function(){
                $("#" + id).trigger("click");
                if($(this).attr('src') == no_tick_image_path(id)){
                    $(this).attr('src', tick_image_path);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).attr('src', no_tick_image_path(id));
                }

            });

            // if we click on the label
            $("label[for='" + id + "']").click(function(){
                if($("#tick_img_" + id).attr('src') == no_tick_image_path(id)){
                    $("#tick_img_" + id).attr('src', tick_image_path);
                }
                else {
                    $("#tick_img_" + id).attr('src', no_tick_image_path(id));
                }
            });

        }

    });
}

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $("input[name='gender']").imageTick({
        tick_image_path: { 
            male: "http://i47.tinypic.com/13yjdac.jpg", 
            female: "http://i49.tinypic.com/261kfia.jpg"
            //"default": "images/gender/default_checked.jpg" //optional default can be used
        },
        no_tick_image_path: { 
            male: "http://i45.tinypic.com/vr4nwy.jpg", 
            female: "http://i47.tinypic.com/2m5mr9s.jpg"
            //"default": "images/gender/default_unchecked.jpg" //optional default can be used
        },
        image_tick_class: "gender",
    });
});
```

I need instructions like where to paste which code (head, body), and what file to make (js, html) also what values to change so it works! Can someone zipp example or something?

Answer (score 2):

We can see the ***full paged*** version of a fiddle by adding an `/show/` at the end.

Save [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mctcs/show/) version of the fiddle. It contains all the scripts and resources needed for that particular fiddle to run.

Compare and meet them in your application.

Comment: Compare what? I don't believe OP has anything in their application yet to compare with.

Comment: @Curt, Compare with his current version, to see if his version meets everything required. Like checking for scripts, or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

## Simplest Solution

[Download jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery), add the `.js` file to your website and add everything in the javascript window (bottom left) into a `script` tag in your `head` tag of your HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  ..script here
</script>
```

Then add your HTML code (top left) into your `body` tag wherever you want these elements to appear.

---

## Better Solution

[Download jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery), add the `.js` file to your website.

The first part of your javascript code is a jQuery plug-in. Create a new javascript file called something like `jquery.imagetick.js`.

Then add the second part to your `head` tag along with script references to your jQuery library and the plugin file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.imagetick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
    $("input[name='gender']").imageTick({
        tick_image_path: { 
            male: "http://i47.tinypic.com/13yjdac.jpg", 
            female: "http://i49.tinypic.com/261kfia.jpg"
            //"default": "images/gender/default_checked.jpg" //optional default can be used
        },
        no_tick_image_path: { 
            male: "http://i45.tinypic.com/vr4nwy.jpg", 
            female: "http://i47.tinypic.com/2m5mr9s.jpg"
            //"default": "images/gender/default_unchecked.jpg" //optional default can be used
        },
        image_tick_class: "gender",
    });
});
</script>
```